# C++ iterating over class

Tags: c++, class

How do I iterate over vector in class e exacly this way below as shown in main

```
class Example{
public:
    vector <int> field;
    Example(){
        for(int i = 0;i< 10 ; i++)
            field.push_back(i);
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Example e();
    
    for (auto x : e){cout << x << endl;}        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR - you need to provide `begin() const` and `end() const` methods for your class

Comment: `Example e();` is broken anyway. It declares a function `e` accepting no arguments and returning an `Example`. That code stands no chance of compiling no matter what the subsequent for-loop looks like. That should read `Example e;`

Comment: How do you implement these two functions begin() and end()?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Could you tell me how to implement these functions?

Comment: The simplest way would be `auto begin() const {return field.begin();}` and same for `end()`, but we don't know if that's precesily what you need. Basically, you return vector iterators, but from your own class.